# How to make QML Menus consider layout mirroring?

Tags: python, qt, qml, pyside6

I'm developing a multi language application including languages that are [rtl](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtquick-positioning-righttoleft.html). When using the [Menu](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qml-qtquick-controls-menu.html) control, they do not follow the `LayoutMirroring.enabled` setting in my top-level [ApplicationWindow](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qml-qtquick-controls-applicationwindow.html).

In left-to-right mode everything looks alright:

[image]

but in right-to-left mode it doesn't work like it is intended. It still opens the menus to the right and also animates it that way.

[image]

And this is what I would expect:
[image]

Here's the code:

```
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls
import QtQuick.Controls.Material

ApplicationWindow {
    id: root

    property bool mirroringEnabled: false

    LayoutMirroring.enabled: mirroringEnabled
    LayoutMirroring.childrenInherit: true

    width: 640
    height: 480
    visible: true

    menuBar: MenuBar {
        Menu {
            id: someMenu
            title: qsTr("&File")
            Action { text: qsTr("&New...") }
        }
        Menu {
            title: qsTr("&Edit")
            Action { text: qsTr("Cu&t") }
        }
        Menu {
            title: qsTr("&Help")
            Action { text: qsTr("&About") }
        }
    }

    Button {
        text: `mirror layout: ${root.mirroringEnabled}`
        anchors.centerIn: root.contentItem

        onClicked: {
            console.log("---")
            console.log("Before:     Menu mirrored:", someMenu.mirrored, "<-")
            console.log("Before: Mirroring enabled:", root.mirroringEnabled)
            root.mirroringEnabled = !root.mirroringEnabled
            console.log("After:     Menu mirrored:", someMenu.mirrored, "<-")
            console.log("After: Mirroring enabled:", root.mirroringEnabled)
        }
    }

}
```

and the code to get that thing running:

```py
from PySide6.QtCore import QUrl
from PySide6.QtQml import QQmlApplicationEngine
from PySide6.QtWidgets import QApplication

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication([])
    engine = QQmlApplicationEngine()

    engine.load(QUrl.fromLocalFile('window.qml'))

    if not engine.rootObjects():
        sys.exit(-1)

    app.exec()
```

Things I've tried:

- Setting the `parent` property on the menu explicitly makes it open to the correct side but messes up the positioning completely
- Switching from a `QApplication` to a `QGuiApplication` doesn't work either

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thank you in advance :)

Comment: It seems that there is a bug, but you can try this to fix it: `Menu { x: -width + parent.width; }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've opened [a bug](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-122392) in their bug tracker. Until it's resolved, I am going to use my workaround based on @smr's idea:

```
Menu {

    readonly property bool mMirrored: root.count > 0 && itemAt(0).mirrored

    x: mMirrored ? -width + parent.width : 0
}
```

So because the `mirrored` property doesn't work on the menu itself, we look it up from the first item :)

Answer (score 1):

You can make a workaround by swapping out `MenuBar` + `Menu` with `RowLayout` + `ToolButton` + `Menu` and some property binding on `x` and `width`:

```
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls
import QtQuick.Layouts
Page {
    id: root
    title: "Menu RTL Sample"
    background: Rectangle { color: "#848895" }
    property bool mirroringEnabled: false
    
    LayoutMirroring.enabled: mirroringEnabled
    LayoutMirroring.childrenInherit: true
    
    width: 640
    height: 480
    visible: true
    
    header: Frame {
        background: Rectangle { color: palette.button }
        padding: 0
        RowLayout {
            width: parent.width
            ToolButton {
                id: fileButton
                text: "&File"
                onClicked: fileMenu.open()
            }
            ToolButton {
                id: editButton
                text: "&Edit"
                onClicked: editMenu.open()
            }
            ToolButton {
                id: helpButton
                text: "&Help"
                onClicked: helpMenu.open()
            }
            Item { Layout.fillWidth: true }
        }
    }
    
    Menu {
        id: fileMenu
        x: root.mirroringEnabled ? fileButton.x - width + fileButton.width : fileButton.x
        MenuItem {
            LayoutMirroring.enabled: root.mirroringEnabled
            LayoutMirroring.childrenInherit: true
            text: "&New..."
        }
    }
    
    Menu {
        id: editMenu
        x: root.mirroringEnabled ? editButton.x - width + editButton.width : editButton.x
        MenuItem {
            LayoutMirroring.enabled: root.mirroringEnabled
            LayoutMirroring.childrenInherit: true
            text: "C&ut"
        }
    }
    
    Menu {
        id: helpMenu
        x: root.mirroringEnabled ? helpButton.x - width + helpButton.width : helpButton.x
        MenuItem {
            LayoutMirroring.enabled: root.mirroringEnabled
            LayoutMirroring.childrenInherit: true
            text: "&About"
        }
    }
    
    Button {
        text: `mirror layout: ${root.mirroringEnabled}`
        anchors.centerIn: root.contentItem
        
        onClicked: {
            console.log("---")
            console.log("Before:     Menu mirrored:", fileMenu.mirrored, "<-")
            console.log("Before: Mirroring enabled:", root.mirroringEnabled)
            root.mirroringEnabled = !root.mirroringEnabled
            console.log("After:     Menu mirrored:", fileMenu.mirrored, "<-")
            console.log("After: Mirroring enabled:", root.mirroringEnabled)
        }
    }
}
```

You can [Try it Online!](https://stephenquan.github.io/qmlonline/?zcode=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)

Comment: Unfortunately, the behavior of the items is different. When you press the File button for instance and you hover over the edit button, you would expect it to be expanded (like in the menu bar) but that doesn't work with this workaround. Still thank you a lot! :)